# Managed to Native Interop on Windows Azure NO P/Invoke

Tags: interop, azure, cloud

Does Azure allow managed to native interop without the use of P/Invoke.  I have a c header file and dll which I plan to wrap in a managed c++ dll, and then wrap that in a c# wrapper for ease of use.

Anyways, the header file is to complicated to use with P/Invoke, and its much easier to use the managed c++ wrapper, however I don't know if this is possible to do in Azure or any other cloud platform such as EC2 ?

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

[Azure does allow native calls, check on this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd573362.aspx)

But it has to be 64 bit only.